# git workflow model & branching

Tags: git, workflow, branch

I've got this interesting link http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
So I have question regarding it:

How to initialize "origin" repo (as bare) or working branch?

When do you do final integration? If the origin is a bare repo then I need to do it on local branch then push it to public(bare) repo?

Best regards,
Peter

Comment: Your question is really confusing to me, it's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: The "origin" repository usually means a remote git server which you will push and pull commits and branches. Do you want to know how to setup a git server?

Comment: You right. Even I can place on my dropbox and have it as server... So it needs to be "bare" repo or repo with working tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you intend to use it as server it should be Bare. So you can push and pull changes and branches from there.

If it is not bare, you would receive a message like this, explaining why it should be bare:

```
  Counting objects: 3, done.
  Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
  Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
  Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 239 bytes, done.
  Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
  Unpacking objects: 100% (2/2), done.
  remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
  remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
  remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
  remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
  remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
  remote: error: 
  remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
  remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
  remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
  remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
  remote: error: other way.
  remote: error: 
  remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
  remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
  To /Users/flores/Code/git-test
   ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
  error: failed to push some refs to '/Users/flores/Code/git-test'
```

Comment: If it is "bare" repo so I can make branches there (on the bare repo). Can I switch the branches? Does it make sense to switch them?

Other question: If I understand I can't work on bare repo as on working tree. So I need to do release, hot-fixes etc... locally and then push it to bare repo. Is it correct?

Comment: Correct. A bare repository is not a development repository is only a repository to fetch and push changes.

Comment: @Pepe, there is a Tick (like this http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Tick_green_modern.svg/364px-Tick_green_modern.svg.png) near my answer :)